# Development server returned response error code: 500 \ React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to build project with Native Code in React Native, but have a problem.

I used official docs on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html, but after react-native run-android i get an error

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHibg.jpg)

Can you help me?

```
The development server returned response error code: 500

URL: http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Body:
{"originModulePath":"D:\\Develop_Drafts\\projectname\\index.js","targetModuleName":"@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault","message":"Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `D:\\Develop_Drafts\\projectname\\index.js`: Module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.\n  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.","errors":[{"description":"Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `D:\\Develop_Drafts\\projectname\\index.js`: Module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.\n  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`."}],"name":"Error","stack":"Error: Unable to resolve module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` from `D:\\Develop_Drafts\\projectname\\index.js`: Module `@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault` does not exist in the Haste module map\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.\n  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.\n    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\\Develop_Drafts\\projectname\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph\\ModuleResolution.js:209:1301)\n    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (D:\\Develop_Drafts\\projectname\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph\\ResolutionRequest.js:83:16)\n    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\\Develop_Drafts\\projectname\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\node-haste\\DependencyGraph.js:238:485)\n    at Object.resolve (D:\\Develop_Drafts\\projectname\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\lib\\transformHelpers.js:180:25)\n    at dependencies.map.result (D:\\Develop_Drafts\\projectname\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:311:29)\n    at Array.map (<anonymous>)\n    at resolveDependencies (D:\\Develop_Drafts\\projectname\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:307:16)\n    at D:\\Develop_Drafts\\projectname\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:164:33\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at step (D:\\Develop_Drafts\\projectname\\node_modules\\metro\\src\\DeltaBundler\\traverseDependencies.js:266:307)"}
processBundleResult
    BundleDownloader.java:296
access$200
    BundleDownloader.java:37
onResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:174
execute
    RealCall.java:153
run
    NamedRunnable.java:32
runWorker
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162
run
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636
run
    Thread.java:764
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gNCm.jpg)

Comment: Could you please add your error as text instead of a image?

Comment: @wagner-michael add full error to post

Comment: return 500 refers to some errors in your server side code, can you trace it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
npm add @babel/runtime

npm install
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! Save my time. 
You are the best!)

My app is running: http://joxi.ru/5mdnvPkI34dEqA.jpg